# how can I read a formatted graph data file Java

Tags: java, input, graph, format

I'm reading graph data for adj matrix, and it is formatted in this way:

```
0
   176     67
   665    185
  1129     26
  1414    114
  1748    205

1
   140    248
   591    175
  1920     68
  2229     31

2
   778    476
   825    447
   888    258
  1179   ....
```

Single number line is the starting vertex, followed by lines of ending vertices with edge length

0 - starting vertex

176 - end vertex

67 - edge length

665 - end vertex

185 - edge length

and so on
That's what I've tried:

```
public void ValueAssign()
         throws IOException {
         Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("list1.txt"));
         String s = inFile.nextLine();
         int NofV = Integer.parseInt(s); // number of vertices
         int NofE = Integer.parseInt(s); // number of edges
         int v1,v2, edge; // v1 - vertex 1, v2 - vertex 2
         while ((s = inFile.nextLine()) != null) {

             Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
             in.useDelimiter(" ");
             v2 = in.nextInt();
             edge = in.nextInt();
         }


    }
```

How can I read it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using scanner and split(), but I just don't know what the code should look like

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @BlackPearl posted, I can't figure out on how to differentiate lines with one or two numbers. `while` inside other one `while` ?

Comment: You can split the line and check if the split array has more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("list1.txt"));
    int startingVertex, endingVertex, edgeLength;
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String trimmedLine = inFile.nextLine().trim();

        //Skip empty lines
        if(trimmedLine.isEmpty()){
            continue;
        }

        String values[] = trimmedLine.split("\\s+");

        if(values.length > 1){
            endingVertex = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            edgeLength = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);

            //Do necessary operations

        }else if(values.length > 0){
            startingVertex = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);

            //Do necessary operations

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).